# Does there exists an entire function satisfying these conditions or not?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struck on this particular question in complex analysis and need help in it .

> Question: Does there exists an entire function f such that $|f(z)|={|z|}^2 \times e^{Im(z)} $ for all z ? If yes then find all such functions .

Unfortunately , I have no clue on what result should I use  to contradict as I am not good in complex analysis .
Can anyone please tell which concept should be used ?

I shall be really thankful.

Comment: $z^{2}e^{-iz}$ is one  such function. Can you prove uniqueness up to a constant factor of modulus $1$?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Sorry If I am making some calculation mistake but I don't think your function satisfies the above condition as |f(z)|= $|z|^2$ and RHS is $|z|^2 \times e^{-z^2 sinz}$ . Can you please clarify ?

Comment: Ben: @Kavi is right. With $z=x+iy$ you have $|e^{-iz}| = |e^{y-ix}| = e^y = e^{Im(z)}$.

Comment: @MartinR thanks!!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you help me in proving uniqueness?

Comment: @Ben If $f$ and $g$ are entire and $|f|=|g|$ consider $\frac f g$. Show that this has removable singularities at the zeros of $g$ so it extends to a bounded entire function.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I am not able to prove it. Do you mind posting an answer for uniqueness?